# Why intermediate map in Gysin sequence is multiplication by Euler class

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, fiber-bundles, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology

I am reading Bott and Tu, Differential Form in Algebraic Topology. At page 178, they constructed Gysin sequence of Sphere Bundle. I am having trouble understanding the argument, $d_{k+1}$ is multiplication by Euler class.       They said, identify an element of $$ E_2^{n-k,k} \cong H^{n-k}(M)\otimes H^{k}(S^k) $$ with $(\pi^{*}(\omega).(-\psi))$, where $\psi$ is the angular form.  They said on the level of forms differential on $E_k$ page, $d_k$ is given by the $\delta$ obstruction of extending a d-cycle to a D cycle of length k.  I am not able to identify the aforementioned construction with this current scenario. Can you please give me some argument or share some insight on the proof?  Thank you.

Comment: Page 20 of the notes: https://web.northeastern.edu/he.wang/Research/spectralsequence.pdf can be helpful with only changes of the notation that $u$ and $x$ takes value in (constant) presheaf.

Comment: Back to Bott&Tu, the problem, in my understanding, is that $(\pi^*\omega)(-\psi)$ is not a well-defined representative in E_2, because $\psi$ is not a closed form. I think we should correct by replacing $(-\psi)$ by $-\sigma^{0,n}$ defined on page 117. Then everything will be fine by observing that $d_{k+1}$ is antiderivation and the definition of $-\pi^*e$ again on page 117.